# ¿como mostrar los datos de un json utilizando javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Mi problema es el siguiente: estoy realizando una tabla en html que me permita mostrar los datos de un archivo json, para eso estoy usando javascript para que me permita insertar filas dependiendo el numero de datos que contenga el archivo json, sin embargo no logro que los datos se muestren.

Este es el archivo json

```
        {
        "humedad": {
            "sensores": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Temperatura 1",
                    "value": 10
                }
            ],
            "sensores2": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Temperatura 2",
                    "value": 10
                }
            ],
            "sensores3": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Temperatura 3",
                    "value": 10
                }
            ]
        }
     }
```

y este es el html y el archivo de javascript

```js
function createTbodySensores(items) {
    var table = document.getElementById("table_sensores");

    // Eliminar el Tbody con los objetos que contenga
    var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody_sensores");
    table.removeChild(tbody);
    // Crea un nuevo Tbody 
    const tbody_sensores = document.createElement("tbody");
    tbody_sensores.id = "tbody_sensores";
    // Agrega las filas dependiendo el número de items
    for (let i = 0; i < items; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var td_id = document.createElement('td');
        var td_name = document.createElement('td');
        var td_value = document.createElement('td');

        td_id.id = "sensor_id" + i;
        td_name.id = "sensor_name" + i;
        td_value.id = "sensor_value" + i

        tr.appendChild(td_id);
        tr.appendChild(td_name);
        tr.appendChild(td_value);

        tbody_sensores.appendChild(tr);
    }
    table.appendChild(tbody_sensores);
}


// Obtiene los datos del archivo JSON
async function getData(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    return response.json();
}

window.setInterval(async function getSensores() {
    // Establece la ruta del archivo JSON
    const url = "/static/js/datos.json";
    const data = await getData(url);
    console.log(data);

    // Sensores toma los datos del objeto sensores
    let sensores = data["humedad"];

    // Se obtiene el numero de elementos
    let items = sensores.length;
    // Se crea un Tbody con el numero de filas
    createTbodySensores(items);

    // Se actualizan los valores de cada fila
    for (let i = 0; i < sensores.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < sensores[i].length; j++)
            var td_id = document.getElementById('sensor_id' + j);
            var td_name = document.getElementById('sensor_name' + j);
            var td_value = document.getElementById('sensor_value' + j);

            td_id.innerHTML = sensores[i][j].id;
            td_name.innerHTML = sensores[i][j].name;
            td_value.innerHTML = sensores[i][j].value;
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Widgets</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/get_sensores.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Sensores</h1>
        <table id="table_sensores">
            <thead id="thead_sensores">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody_sensores">
                <!-- Se agregarán una fila por cada item en el archivo json -->
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script>
            document.onload = getSensores();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

cuando lo pruebo no me aparecen los datos pero al inspeccionar e ir a consola me aparece esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente igual tomar los datos desde el campo "sensores", utilizando solo asi un solo ciclo para obtener los datos y funciona, pero requiero que pueda tomarlos todos desde el campo "humedad"
¿alguna idea de lo que estoy haciendo mal y como podria darle solucion a esto?

Comment: ¿Y esto porque lo pones? `document.onload = getSensores();`  Eso da error al ejecutarse y quizás esta parando el setInterval por eso.  Mira de comentarlo a ver si así te funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como tienes tu json, te propongo que cambies el window.setInterval por esto:

```
window.setInterval(async function getSensores() {
    // Establece la ruta del archivo JSON
    const url = "/static/js/datos.json";
    const data = await getData(url);

    // Sensores toma los datos del objeto sensores
    let sensores = data["humedad"];
    
    // Se obtiene el numero de elementos
    let items = Object.keys(sensores).length

    // Se crea un Tbody con el numero de filas
    createTbodySensores(items);

    // establecemos un contador para el siguiente bucle
    contador = 0

    // recorremos las propiedades del objeto 
    for (let key in sensores) {
      var td_id = document.getElementById('sensor_id' + contador);
      var td_name = document.getElementById('sensor_name' + contador);
      var td_value = document.getElementById('sensor_value' + contador);

      td_id.innerHTML = sensores[key][0].id;
      td_name.innerHTML = sensores[key][0].name;
      td_value.innerHTML = sensores[key][0].value;
      contador++
    }
}, 1000);
```

De esta forma estás recorriendo correctamente las propiedades del objeto **data** recibido, las cuales almacenan un array de un elemento cada una, y que invocamos mediante el `[0]`.

Comment: Gracias en verdad, llevaba un tiempo intentando y no lograba mucho.

Comment: De nada :-)  A veces cuesta ver lo que tienes delante, si es un objeto, una propiedad, un array de objetos, etc... pero una vez lo identificas es cuestión de buscar las funciones correctas para su recorrido y ya está. Saludos!